# How to clear /WiFi/WiFiManager directory in iOS?

Tags: ios, libimobiledevice

I want get [ios crash log files](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/AnalyzingCrashReports/AnalyzingCrashReports.html)(ips) from iPhone device.
So I am using [idevicecrashreport](https://github.com/libimobiledevice/libimobiledevice/blob/master/tools/idevicecrashreport.c) from libimobiledevice

> idevicecrashreport --extract .
>   Move: /WiFi/WiFiManager/wifi-09-15-2016__01:07:00.log
>   Move: /WiFi/WiFiManager/wifi-09-15-2016__01:07:01.log
>   Move: /WiFi/WiFiManager/wifi-buf-10-25-2016__07:06:43.log
>   Move: /WiFi/WiFiManager/wifi-buf-10-25-2016__09:45:05.log
>   Move: /WiFi/WiFiManager/wifi-buf-10-25-2016__09:45:15.log
>   Move: /WiFi/WiFiManager/wifi-buf-10-25-2016__12:34:33.log
>   Move: /com.apple.appstored/appstored.log
>   Move: /com.apple.itunesstored/itunesstored.log
>   Done.

As You can see in output, command also pull WiFi logs from device.
Problems is that sometimes I can have hundreds of WiFi log files which make `idevicecrashreport` command execution unacceptable time consuming.

Solution will be find a way to remove /WiFi/WiFiManager from device